# How to add another file extension (e.g. 'style.less') to Vim's snipMate plugin?

Tags: vim, snipmate

I would like to write snippets for Less (.less) and Stylus (.styl) and use then in Vim's snipMate plugin. How can I accomplish that?

EDIT: I know that the first step is to create a file inside the **snippets** folder with a name like this: `less.snippets` or `stylus.snippets` but after that I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: did you eventually create yours? Also, did you know abwt this snippets [repo](https://github.com/honza/snipmate-snippets/tree/master/snippets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes right that is the first step. And after that you have to set the [filetype](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27filetype%27) of the files you want to edit with multiple snippets to:

```
set filetype=less.styl
```

or

```
set filetype=styl.less
```

I've just tested it with the [snipmate "official" fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) and it works fine but I'm sure enough it should work with the original plugin too.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, what's new with that fork?

Comment: @alexchenco A lot of things! It's a bit more difficult to install because it has some dependencies. But surely it's worth a try. The best thing with new fork is autocompletion of snippets that start with the same letters, I love that feature.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. You are right, it is difficult to install (still trying to figure out how).